# EER Diagram MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a database in MySQL Workbench using Ubuntu.

Is there a quick way to get an EER diagram of that database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MySQL Workbench you can reverse engineer a database into an EER model. See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html) for details.

> For a visual representation (EER diagram) of this schema, select
>   Model, Create Diagram from Catalog Objects to create the EER Diagram
>   for the model.

There are [binaries available](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html) or a PPA depending on your version of ubuntu. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/) for details on the apt repository or install from source.